# How do I add an additional item to my cart?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, innerhtml

with my current code, I have my added items which are in my localstorage, but it only shows me one in my basket

and I don't see how to solve my problem, do you have any idea?

```html
function displayPanier(product) {
  
   function getTeddies() {
    let teddiesPanier = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basketProducts"));
    return teddiesPanier; 
   }
   
   
   let teddiesPanier = getTeddies();

   //faire une boucle pour iterrer sur les produits dans le local storage

   function panierTeddies (){
     
   
       const panierStorage = document.getElementById("test")
       panierStorage.innerHTML = `
       <table class="table bg-light">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Photo</th>
            <th scope="col">Nom</th>
            <th scope="col">Prix</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td><img id=panierImg class="img-fluid" src="${teddiesPanier[0].imageUrl}"  style="max-width: 40px;"></td>
            <td><h5 class="font card-title">${teddiesPanier[0].name}</h5></td>
            <td><p class="card-text prix">${teddiesPanier[0].price / 100}€</p></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <td><button onclick="removeProduct('${product}')" class="btn btn-primary">Supprimer</button></td>

   `
   }
   console.table(teddiesPanier)
   panierTeddies();
}
```

[screenshhot basket with localstroage in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KMBw.png)

Comment: describe your context, also try adding some debug code and show the console output, tell us what you have tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only shows (1) item because you didn't iterate over the array of items from your localStorage. e.g. ${teddiesPanier[0].name}.

What you can do is modify the code into this:

```js
  panierStorage.innerHTML = `
       <table class="table bg-light">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Photo</th>
            <th scope="col">Nom</th>
            <th scope="col">Prix</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>`;

      for (var i=1; i < teddiesPanier.length; i++) {
panierStorage.innerHTML += `
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">${i}</th>
              <td><img id=panierImg class="img-fluid" src="${teddiesPanier[i].imageUrl}"  style="max-width: 40px;"></td>
              <td><h5 class="font card-title">${teddiesPanier[i].name}</h5></td>
              <td><p class="card-text prix">${teddiesPanier[i].price / 100}€</p></td>
            </tr>
            `;
      }

panierStorage.innerHTML += `<td><button onclick="removeProduct('${product}')" class="btn btn-primary">Supprimer</button></td></tbody>
      </table>`;
```

Comment: you let a `teddiesPanier[0]` in the first `td` tag

Comment: @SylvainChaugny thanks i'm having a hard time formatting im an f'in noob at stackoverflow hahahah

Answer (score 0):

Well you only use `teddiesPanier[0]`, which is the first element of your array, so obviously you won't display the other items if there are any. You should make a loop to generate the `tr` scopes or something...

Which is precisely what you wrote in your comment in a beautiful French which should totally be written in English, along with all your variables and function names !